# How to pass value to method of wsdl client using pysimplesoap

Tags: python, pysimplesoap

```
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient
client = SoapClient(wsdl="https://platform.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.MediaMind.API/V2/AuthenticationService.svc?wsdl")
auth_token = client.ClientLogin(username = 'user', password = 'pass',
                                 applicationKey = 'test')

#I got authenticated here

token=  auth_token['ClientLoginResult']

campaign_client =  SoapClient(wsdl="https://platform.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.MediaMind.API/V2/CampaignService.svc?wsdl"
                                  ,trace = False)
```

There is simple method I want to call get contact definition below

```
Show    
    Parameters  

    Name    Type    Description
    ContactID   Int32   The contact ID. Mandatory field.
    UserSecurityToken   String  Contains a string that uniquely identifies the current Sizmek Trafficking API session. You may retrieve the token after logging into the AuthenticationService
```

_

```
Show    
Response    

Name    Type    Description
Contact     ContactInfo     Returns the contact information used by ContactInfo
```

I believe I am not able to pass parameters correctly here.
That's why wrong request is formed

```
test = {'UserSecurityToken' :token,'ContactID' : 1  }
data = campaign_client.GetContact(test )
```

In WSDL client I can see the code below to get method with parameters.

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
        """Return a pseudo-method that can be called"""
        if not self.services:  # not using WSDL?
            return lambda self=self, *args, **kwargs: self.call(attr, *args, **kwargs)
        else:  # using WSDL:
            return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.wsdl_call(attr, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: After using campaign_client.GetContact(UserSecurityToken=test['UserSecurityToken'], ContactId=test['ContactID']...still getting below error

Comment: Error:%s Invalid Args Structure. Errors: [u"Argument key UserSecurityToken not in parameter. parameter: {u'ContactID': <type 'int'>}, args: {'ContactID': 1, 'UserSecurityToken': u'4bb80e33-ff69-486e-826f-b27ecd2396be'}"]

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to unpack keyword arguments from a `dict`, and you need to use `**kwarg` notation for that:

```
data = campaign_client.GetContact(**test)
```

Checkout this Python docs page: [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: thanks @Lawrence but still getting error Error: %s Invalid Args Structure. Errors: [u"Argument key UserSecurityToken not in parameter. parameter: {u'ContactID': <type 'int'>}, args: {'ContactID': 1, 'UserSecurityToken': u'f38e6844-e9e4-46fd-b0c0-68ff85e313e7'}"] error

Comment: The function is expecting to get UserSecurityToken as a parameter, so you will have to pass it without unpacking, ckeck the update.

Comment: @sagar: I removed the update, previous solution should work. Does this work: `campaign_client.GetContact(UserSecurityToken=test['UserSecurityToken'], ContactId=test['ConcactID'])`?

Comment: Also, check the value of `token`, it might be empty. Print it out after you create it.

Comment: no still geting Error:%s 'ConcactID' tryed to changing ConatactID to "1" also still same error

Comment: I also checked token its not empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76608/discussion-between-sagar-and-lawrence).

Comment: @sagar I would try to run this locally, but I don't have the credentials. Is there some kind of demo or testing credentials for use with this service?